# Why was Spencer Fox replaced by Huck Milner as Dashiell "Dash" Parr in Incredibles 2?

Tags: casting, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

[*Incredibles 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incredibles_2) is released and I noticed that [Huck Milner](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm9133740/) did the voice for  *Dashiell "Dash" Parr* in the movie. In the first film [*The Incredibles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredibles), [Spencer Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Fox) was the one to voice the character.

Why was he replaced? Most of the other voice cast have remained the same.

Comment: I don't know what world you live in, but where I live, most ten year olds kinda stop being ten years old after 15 years.

Comment: @noClue well, the voices. The actual words? Ehhhh not so much.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This was [explained by **Brad Bird** (the director of the movie)](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/07/14/main-incredibles-cast-return-for-sequel-with-one-exception) at the D23 Expo in June 2017:

> Director Brad Bird revealed at D23 Expo that, with the exception of
>   Dash's Spencer Fox, the main cast from *The Incredibles* will return for
>   *Incredibles 2*.
>
> [...]
>
> Bird explained at the D23 Expo animation panel that **they needed to
>   recast Dash in order to make sure his character still sounded like a
>   10-year-old boy.** *Incredibles 2* takes place a minute after the end
>   of the original, so **Bird wanted to avoid Dash suddenly having a much
>   deeper voice.**

Spencer was ten or eleven when the first movie was made, and now he is twenty-five: thus he doesn't sound like an ten year old anymore (which Dash is supposed to be).

FYI Spencer had already been "replaced" as Dash by [Raymond Ochoa](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Raymond_Ochoa): he voiced Dash in several video games ([Disney Infinity](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Disney_Infinity), [Kinect Rush: A Disney/Pixar Adventure](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Kinect_Rush:_A_Disney/Pixar_Adventure), ...).

Comment: As the Brady Kids sang: "When it's time to change, you've got to rearrange."

Comment: Tangential comment - John Morris was the voice of Andy for all three Toy Story movies.  Although, that worked since they aged Andy as well, so it "matched up" with John's voice as he grew.

Comment: "Spencer was ten or eleven when the first movie was made, and now he is twenty-five" wow that makes me feel old.